# Why doesn't the FuncAnimation from the MatplotLib module display the graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot live data (data that keeps on updating) using FuncAnimation from the MatplotLib module. When I run the program, the graph doesn't display. The program doesn't give any errors, but displays the following message when I run the program: "Figure size 576x396 with 0 Axes"

Here's my code to plot the live data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('seaborn')

def animate(i):
    df = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
    x = df['x_value']
    y1 = df['total1']
    y2 = df['total2']

    plt.cla()

    plt.plot(x, y1, label='Line1')
    plt.plot(x, y2, label = 'Line2')

    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here's the csv file I created for the program:

```
import random
import csv
import time
import pandas as pd

x_value = 0
total1 = 10000
total2 = 10000

fieldnames = ['x_value','total1','total2']
with open('data2.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()

while True:
    with open('data2.csv','a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        info = {
            'x_value': x_value,
            'total1' : total1,
            'total2' : total2   
        }

        csv_writer.writerow(info)
        print(x_value, total1, total2)

        x_value += 1 
        total1 = total1 + random.randint(-6,8)
        total2 = total2 + random.randint(9,11)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you use jupyter-notebook?

Comment: For an animation, the plot should be created first, outside the animate function. Inside the function, the plot can be updated with new values. [Here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) you can find an interesting tutorial.

Comment: @DennisLi Yes I do

Answer (score 0):

The message, `<Figure size 576x396 with 0 Axes>` , is showing the location where the graph is saved. Removing plt.show() shows the plot.